# Android Debugging?

Tags: android, debugging

What is the best way to debug an android application?
Every once in a while the application crashes, an it says application has stopped unexpectedly, it never says why it crashes, or where in my code, what's the bet way to find the reason for crashes, and exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several ways to do that, activate the **LogCat** and you will see there detailed info about what happens with your App.

or you will implement an error Handling sending the Exception info to a Toast

```
 try {
    ...
    your code
    ...
 } catch (IOException e) { 
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception Info " +     e.getCause(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

updated

Comment: This is bad. You should really let the exception crash the application if you're not going to handle it in some meaningful way.

Comment: hi ognian , I think sometimes is better show the Error message to the users than show the ugly message "application has stopped unexpectedly" and force to close the entire app =(

Comment: It's bad practice to display the full e.getMessage() to the user though.  Dialog should explain what went wrong, not give a stack trace.  Plus, there are security issues with this approach.  You don't know what's in that message.  I've had my SQL queries and database schema exposed this way :P

Comment: hehe Ok i understand the approach, even more if the toast just show the info few seconds :P, and this never can't be in a release version.

Comment: @Elenasys You have added one `)` too much. here --> `e.getCause())`

Comment: @user8 I have edited that detail, Thank you very much my friend!

Answer (score 5):

Your best approach is to include a bug and crash reporting service in your app. A good example is [Instabug](https://instabug.com) which can deliver all users crashes automatically to the product's dashboard in the background as soon as one occurs.

Reports are combined in one dashboard and they give you insights about crashes on each app version, crash severity, and more.

Every crash report also includes a plenty of details including:

- The crash stack trace
- All Network and console logs
- An environment snapshot
- Visual reproduction steps

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ADB just launch your app in debugging mode to gain a possibility to watch variables/expressions at runtime.
You also can see the stacktrace in a Logcat window of your IDE if your app crashes.

Comment: You can find logcat window on window > show view > other, and then search for logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android's Log class, and logcat, for example:

*Log.d( "Your app name", "The value of x is: " + x );*

And in logging output you'll get something like:

*D/Your app name( 1001): The value of x is: 96*

You can get logging output from command line by running: "adb logcat", or using Dalvik debug monitor (ddms in the tools directory of Android SDK)

Using Log is superior to using Toasts since Toasts are gone quite quickly, and logcat will show you a lot of information upon application crash (like filename and line number which caused unhandled exception)

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch the logs by DDMS tool by android.
Just type [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) in cmd and it will show u a GUI with running logs and more stuff for debugging.